# How many communities can i add into salesforce?

Tags: community

Is there a limit related to the number of communities I can create for a single salesforce instance?

In case there is a limit, is the limit dependent on

- the salesforce edition (for developer account)?
- the type of community?

I want to know about the developer account.Is there any limit for creating custom domain or custom url for developer account community?
Because when I created the new community it takes the url of earlier created community.Can I set the new domain or url for the new community?
As I am not able to add new domain because I have already created one but I don't want to use it for this one.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the use case and version of Salesforce? Your Question is rather broad in the manner it's asked. On purchases licenses by Community User and Type of User when creating a Community. One could just as easily ask you how many licenses and what type of license do you want to purchase?

Comment: @crmprogdev I want to know about the developer account.Is there any limit for creating custom domain or custom url for developer account community?

Answer (score 1):

From Winter '14 Release you can check maximum number of active Communities for Organisation - Setup->Build->Communities->All Communities

From post on developer.salesforce:

> Salesforce provisions one community per Communities license block purchased. It’s usually a good practice to keep communities to a minimum to avoid creating siloed communities and reduce administration efforts.

and another bit:

> Customers with Communities licenses on PROD can perform a Sandbox refresh to get those licenses on Sandbox. Customers on Developer Edition orgs get 10 licenses of each Communities license type.

So there's no public answer to your question. I believe you have to contact Salesforce.

Link to post https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/02/salesforce-communities-licenses.html